# How to dynamically update react components on page after sidekiq job succeed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, react-rails

I have a sidekiq jobs in my rails application.
And I have a few react components on my site.

How can I make my rails app page automatically update after the sidekiq job succeeds?

Comment: Not familiar with Ruby or Sidekiq but why can't this process have a callback function that either renders the React component directly and or wrap all the React.render() calls into a single function and call that?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/chrismccord/sync

Comment: @MZaragoza hm.. this is solution, but this isn't good thing. How reactjs will react on dom changing without virtual DOM changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that best way is to send websocket to react. So, react should listen for a websockets.